# Python Bar Plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, data-science

Below is the code that I am using to generate the bar plots and I want to display the respective values above the plot:

```
import numpy as np
import folium
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.ma.bench import xl
from wordcloud import WordCloud,STOPWORDS
import matplotlib as mp
import seaborn as sns

df=pd.read_csv("Topic_Survey_Assignment.csv",index_col=0) # reading csv file
df.sort_values("Very interested", ascending = False)
df_p=(df/2233)*100
df_p=round(df_p,2)
xlist=[]
ylist=[]
c=["#5cb85c","#5bc0de","#d9534f"]
a=df_p.plot(kind='bar',figsize=(20,8),color=c)     # plotting bar plot
plt.xlabel('Subjects',fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel('Percentage of People',fontsize=14)
plt.title('Data Science Statistics',fontsize=20)
plt.legend(fontsize=14)

plt.show(a)
print(xlist)
```

Plot Image

[image]

Comment: please provide sample data

Comment: https://cocl.us/datascience_survey_data - Sample Data

Answer (score 2):

You can add annotations to the bar plot like this:

```
for p in ax.patches:
    ax.annotate(str(p.get_height()), (p.get_x() + 0.08, p.get_height()), va='bottom', ha='center')
```

Here is an example with randomly generated data:

```
# Generate sample data
c=["#5cb85c","#5bc0de","#d9534f"]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df_p.plot(ax = plt.gca(), kind='bar',figsize=(12,8),color=c)     # plotting bar plot
plt.xlabel('Subjects',fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel('Percentage of People',fontsize=14)
plt.title('Data Science Statistics',fontsize=20)
plt.legend(fontsize=14)
plt.tight_layout()

for p in ax.patches:
    ax.annotate(str(p.get_height()), (p.get_x()+0.08, p.get_height()),
                va='bottom', ha='center', weight='bold')
```

[image: Bar plot with annotations]

Comment: Actually, this solution will not have that problem. I will edit the sample text to match the one used in the plot.

Comment: Thank You Nathaniel but the data to displayed is present in the dataframe 'df_p'.

Comment: Is there any way to add the values to  which the bar corresponds above the bar

Comment: Also can you explain the working this portion of the code-                                                            fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df_p.plot(ax = plt.gca()